# UISearchBar issue in displaying search result

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, nssortdescriptor

In my app I have 3 `NSMutableArray`s namely `empJsonArray`  `searchArray` and `nameArray`

`empJsonArray` is populated using JSON.
 `nameArray` is populated with `valueForKey:@"Name"` from `empJsonArray` and `searchArray` is initially populated with contents of `empJsonArray`.

the data is displayed in a `UITableView`

Now I am using `UISearchBar` for searching through my `UITableView` and display the relevant data. `UISearchBar` is working fine but the problem arises when the search data is displayed.
suppose I have 2 names that contain letter "T" when I search for "T" `UITableView` display 2 items but form the top of the `nameArray` (i.e. index 0 and 1) not the items that contain "T".

I am also using `NSSortDescriptor`.

Here's the code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MYCell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MYCell"];
}
sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
sortedArray = [self.empJsonArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];
nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[sortedArray valueForKey:@"Name"]];

return cell;

}
```

Search Method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

if ([searchText length]==0) {
    [searchArray removeAllObjects];
    [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:nameArray];

}
else {
    [searchArray removeAllObjects];
    for (NSString *string in nameArray) {
        NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
            [searchArray addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
[empTable reloadData];

}
```

you can see the screenshots here 
1.[Before search](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42881080/1.png)
2.[After Search](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42881080/2.png)

Comment: hey ankur i think you need to manage one flag for searching like if(flag){table cell }else{tablecell}.manage two array for this...

Comment: @SarafarazBabi I am sorry I don't understand can you please elaborate ?

Comment: sorry I replied too fast. I am on it will tell you if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Instead of displaying the search result in `cell`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

I was displaying

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];
```